# Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Phalcon\Di::$_default ....public/index.php on line 20

Tags: php, phalcon, centos7

I've installed Phalcon on my server Centos 7 with PHP-FPM 5.6

I'm following the basic instructions at https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html and get stuck at the beginning:

Sometimes it displays the correct "Hello!" message, but I've refreshed the page several times and most of the time I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Phalcon\Di::$_default in /var/www/vhosts/playerm8.com/httpdocs/public/index.php on line 20

My public/index.php looks like this:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlProvider;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;

try {

    // Register an autoloader
    $loader = new Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        '../app/controllers/',
        '../app/models/'
    ))->register();

    // Create a DI
    $di = new FactoryDefault()
;
    // Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function () {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
        return $view;
    });

    // Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
    $di->set('url', function () {
        $url = new UrlProvider();
        $url->setBaseUri('/');
        return $url;
    });

    // Handle the request
    $application = new Application($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
     echo "Exception: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

And my apps/controllers/IndexController.php looks like this:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "<h1>Hello!</h1>";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The static property `Phalcon\Di::$_default` should always be defined. There's probably something wrong with your build. But you can try `$di = new FactoryDefault();` with the semicolon on the same line and see if it helps. Then move the line to the top of the try-catch. If it still doesn't work, try commenting out all your code and see if you can get just `$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();` to work (without relying on the namespace). If that fails part of the time, it's the build.

Comment: Why it would work part of the time and not the other part sounds very fishy to me. It could also be something stupid like having two versions of the same file open and saving changes to the wrong one which could explain the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, the code was correct, but apparently it was something to do with Plesk.
I've removed Plesk from the server and installed Apache and it now works all the time.
Thanks to the people who replied anyway :)